# FullCalendar - get current resource in navLinkDayClick

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, fullcalendar-scheduler

i am using FullCalendar Scheduler, and view "agendaWeek"

is it possible get current resource ID inside this event?:

```
navLinkDayClick: function(date, jsEvent)
```

I need to get resource id when user click on nav link day.

Thanks

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/navLinkDayClick), no this property is not exposed. Perhaps you could make a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features). Why do you need to know, though?? Maybe there's some other way to achieve whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. i need to make ajax call when user click on navLinkDay, this call will generate custom report for Resource in exact day.

Comment: I don't think you can do it like that unfortunately. You'll have to give the user another way to select the resource they are interested in

Comment: Hi, thanks. I solved it, by adding custom event with text "Print" to event list as ALL DAY event, and then i added custom logic to eventClick.